What are the specific conditions on which an unequal probability sample is better than a simple random sample?
Suppose you are sampling from a population of size $N$ with replacement $n$ times, with sampling probabilities $p_i$ summing to 1. You can estimate the population total $\tau=\sum y_i$ with the Hanson Hurwitz estimator, $\hat \tau = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i\in S}\frac{y_i}{p_i}$. This can give an estimator with lower variance than you'd get by simple random sampling as long as the $p_i$'s are chosen correctly. My question is: what are specific conditions on the relationship between $p_i$ and $y_i$ to make this true? The general idea is you'd want larger $p_i$'s for larger $y_i$'s, but is there some specific way to describe this? Maybe letting $Y$ and $P$ be the random variables associated with choosing $i$ at random and observing $y_i$ and $p_i$ we can say something like, the covariance of $Y$ and $P$ has to be positive, though I don't think that this is actually the correct answer.
